# Filter google calendar event list with the query parameter "q"

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to filter a list of recently updated events from my Google Calendar with the parameter `q= "status ='confirmed'"` but it returns nothing.

I first had my block of code like this :

```
def main():
    watchEvents(monday) # monday is in isoformat : "2021-09-13T00:00:00Z"

def watchEvents(day):
    page_token = None
    while True:
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, updatedMin=day).execute()
        for event in events['items']:
            print (event['summary'])
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
```

But the parameter `updatedMin=day` outputs an error `Traceback (most recent call last): print (event['summary']) KeyError: 'summary'`, because cancelled events don't have those properties.
Here is an example of a cancelled event when I try the API on the [google site](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list):

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"xxxxxxx\"",
   "id": "xxxxx",
   "status": "cancelled"
  }
```

I don't want those type of events where the status are "cancelled" so I tried the parameter `q= "status ='confirmed'"` in my code :

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, updatedMin=day, q= "status ='confirmed'").execute()
```

But now it returns an empty list, even when I try the API on the [google site](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) :

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"xxxxx\"",
 "summary": "FirstName Name private",
 "updated": "2021-09-16T10:04:02.008Z",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Brussels",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "XXXXXXXXX=",
 "items": []
}
```

So my questions are :

- What is the syntax to filter the status of the events ?
- Or is there another way to get a list of the last updated items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The Google Calendar API always returns cancelled events for `events: list` when either `updateMin` or `syncToken` are specified in the request. If you wish to remove updated items that have been deleted, this will need to be done locally.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on the event resource: (emphasis my own):

> | Property name | Value | Description | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `status` | `string` | Status of the event. Optional. Possible values are: • "`confirmed`" - The event is confirmed. This is the default status. • "`tentative`" - The event is tentatively confirmed. • "`cancelled`" - The event is cancelled (deleted). ***The [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method returns cancelled events only on incremental sync (when `syncToken` or `updatedMin` are specified) or if the `showDeleted` flag is set to true.*** The [get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) method always returns them. | writable |

and from `events: list`:

> | Parameter name | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `updatedMin` | `datetime` | Lower bound for an event's last modification time (as a [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) timestamp) to filter by. ***When specified, entries deleted since this time will always be included regardless of `showDeleted`.*** Optional. The default is not to filter by last modification time. |

You can use a `syncToken` to retrieve updates from the last time you made a sync request, but even then `cancelled` events will be returned.

Additionally, it appears that the event status can't be specified using the `q` parameter to have results filtered in the response.

Answer (score 1):

The q parameter works somewhat strangely, in that you set it to a string that serves as a keyword which gets searched for in the following fields of the events: summary, description, location, attendee's displayName, attendee's email.

So, let's say you want to get events that take place at the location Times Square.  You would use the following sort of statement:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token, q='Times Square').execute()
```

Now hopefully you don't have an event taking place in Paris that has an attendee with the display name Times Square, or else that event will also be included in the events result set -- since, sadly, you can't specify which particular field q's search should apply to.